# How to exclude a dependency from built JAR in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, sbt

I have the current dependency specified in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
        implementation("com.thesamet.scalapb:scalapb-runtime-grpc_2.13:0.11.1")
}
```

And I want to exclude it from my built JAR. In `sbt` it would be enough with doing:

```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % "0.11.1" % Optional
)
```

But how can be the same done in Gradle? I have seen in some post that they use `compile.exclude` to exclude transitive dependencies, but that is not a transitive dependency, so not sure if just using `compile.exclude` would be fine (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```
dependencies {
      compileOnly "com.thesamet.scalapb:scalapb-runtime-grpc_2.13:0.11.1"
}
```

ref: https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies